# Interval of validity of the IVP of an exact ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The $(x-2y)y'=2x-y$ can be shown to be an exact ODE. Given the initial condition $y(1)=3$ I found the following particular solution $y(x)=\frac{1}{2}(x+\sqrt{28-3x^2})$. I have checked my results with Matlab.

My textbook asks for the interval of validity of the this particular solution. For real values of the square root one has $-\sqrt{28/3} \leq x\leq \sqrt{28/3}$. Since $x=1$ belongs to this interval, I conclude that the interval of validity is $-\sqrt{28/3} \leq x\leq \sqrt{28/3}$. Nevertheless, the textbook says that it is $1\leq x\leq \sqrt{28/3}$.

1. Am I missing something here?
2. I know that the ode being a nonlinear one, intervals of validity can depend on the value of
   $y_0$ for an initial condition of the form $y(t_0)=y_0$.

   a. For what values of $(t_0,y_0)$ does this ode posses non-unique solution?

   b. For what values of $(t_0,y_0)$ does this ode posses a unique solution?

   c. For what values of $(t_0,y_0)$ does this ode posses infinitely many solutions?

   d. For what values of $(t_0,y_0)$ does this ode posses no solutions at all?

Comment: Since $x=1$ is the initial point, so the validity of the ODE is $1\le  x \le \sqrt{28/3}$

Comment: This depends on context. If the textbook is overall only concerned with forward solutions, then obviously the left part of the maximal domain is not of interest. There might also be an explicit restriction of the domain to $x\ge 1$ somewhere close to the tasks. Generally you are right in that the full interval should be the solution.